# Standardizing the height and width of a user submitted picture

Tags: android, image, uiimageview

I am building an Android application and one of the specs is that the user must be able to upload a profile picture. What is the best way to go about standardizing the height and width of pictures that I receive from a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bitmapfactory to check the size of file and and scale down the image 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html